# Equivalence relations proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

I need to prove that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are equivalence relations on the set $A$, then $R_1\cap R_2$ is an equivalence relation. Problem is I dont know how. Please help!

Comment: Note: Under the relation $R_1 \cap R_2$, $x \sim_{R_1 \cap R_2} y$ if $x \sim_{R_1} y$ and $x \sim_{R_2} y$.

Answer (score 1):

Since both are reflexive, $(x,x) \in R_1$ and $(x,x) \in R_2$. $(x,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2$.

Suppose $(x,y) \in R_1 \cap R_2$. $(x,y) \in R_1$ and $(x,y) \in R_2$. Since both are symmetric $(y,x) \in R_1$ and $(y,x) \in R_2$. Hence $(y,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2$.

Suppose $(x,y), (y,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2$. Hence $(x,y), (y,z) \in R_1$ and $(x,y), (y,z) \in R_2$. Since both are transitive, $(x,z) \in R_1$ and $(x,z) \in R_2)$. Hence $(x,z) \in R_1 \cap R_2$.

It has been shown that $R_1 \cap R_2$ is an equivalence relation.